Change of order of integration to derive $E[g(x)]$
I am reading A first Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross, where I saw the following equation:
$$E(Y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(Y>y)dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{y}^{\infty} f_{Y}(x)dxdy$$
Now I don't understand how changing the order of integration yields
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} P(Y>y)dy =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\int_{0}^{x} dy\right) f_{Y}(x) \, dx
$$
Can anyone explain the reasoning behind this step?
In addition, the continuation of the derivation looks like this
$$E(g(X)) = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(Y>y)dy
 $$
And how is this last step done?
$$= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{x:g(x)>y}^{} f(x)dxdy = \int_{x:g(x)>0}^{} \int_{0}^{g(x)} dy f(x)dx $$

In the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{y}^{\infty} f_{Y}(x)dxdy$$
$y$ varies from $0$ to $+\infty$, and, for a fixed value of $y$, $x$ moves in the range $[y,+\infty]$.
This can equivalently be expressed as $x$ moving in $[0,+\infty]$ and, for a fixed value of $x$, $y$ belonging to $[0,x]$ (as $x$ must be greater than or equal to $y$).
Thus, changing the order of integration yields $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\int_{0}^{x} dy\right) f_{Y}(x) \, dx,$$
as written in the book.
Similarly, in $$= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{x:g(x)>y}^{} f(x)dxdy $$
we have $y\in[0,+\infty]$ and $g(x)\in[y,+\infty]$. This is equivalent to $g(x)\in [0,+\infty]$ and $y\in [0,g(x)]$, so the integral is the same as $$\int_{x:g(x)>0}^{}\left( \int_{0}^{g(x)} dy\right) f(x)dx$$

Thank you, I am starting to get the gist of how it works. I am still a bit confused of whether the $y$ variable is actually fixed or changing, as in the first integral, it is fixed from $y$ to $\infty$, however in the outer one, $y$ changes. And if we do it according to your logic, isn't it that x moves from the range $[y, \infty]$ before $y$ moves, as we analyze the integral inside first? Like I still feel that the ordering of the logic is different.

$y$ is changing, but the range of $x$ depends on $y$, so we have to 'fix' $y$ in order to get the range of $x$. This change of order is formally justified by Tonelli's and Fubini's Theorems; Ross is probably assuming the conditions of them.
